# Vector2i Array in C#

Tags: c#, sfml

I have line in C++:

```
sf::Vector2i map[100][100];
```

and I have no idea how to write this in C#.
Then I've used this like this:

```
map[loadCounter.x][loadCounter.y] = sf::Vector2i(-1,-1);
```

Could someone help me how to write these lines in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array declarations look a little different in C#. You have a rectangular array in C++, but the syntax is closer to that of a jagged array in C#. A jagged array so that all elements have the same length can serve the same purpose as a rectangular array.

[Rectangular array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx):

```
sf.Vector2i[,] map = new sf.Vector2i[100,100];
map[loadCounter.x,loadCounter.y] = new sf.Vector2i(-1,-1);
```

[Jagged array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx):

```
sf.Vector2i[][] map = new sf.Vector2i[100][];
for (int i = 0; i<100; i++)
    map[i] = new sf.Vector2i[100];
map[loadCounter.x][loadCounter.y] = new sf.Vector2i(-1,-1);
```

These assume that there is a corresponding namespace `sf` with a type `Vector2i` that has a constructor taking (-1,-1) as parameters.